# Animating word in a string

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to animate the last word of a sentence and since I'm doing this on squarespace I'm a little stuck.

The string in trying to animate doesn't have a specific identifier (it's dynamic and changes on page load) and I can't add span to it. I can however isolate the world I'm trying to animate by bolding it (managed to use CSS to specifically change the color of this word to verify it's been isolated).

What I'd like to do is animate this bolded word to fade in and out and be replaced by other words from an array using JavaScript and an animation library. Anyone ever done this before or has any recommendations?

Comment: please post your existing code here.

Comment: If you're able to select the string with CSS, then you can definitely select it with JS; and then wrap it into a `span`. From there on, happy animating.

Comment: Hi Gabriel and Thomas,

My existing code so far is only 

#intro .desc-wrapper p > strong {    
  font-size: 60px;
  }

I've essentially identified the class. The actual HMTL I can't play around with since I'm using Squarespace, but the paragraph or rather word that I want to animate is changed with that class.

Comment: @AlekP, please use the `@` notation when answering someone, so we get notified that you answered. Besides that, OK you have a `<strong>` node. for this it's as good as a `<span>`. You have the CSS-selector to fetch the node; with `jQuery` for example. Now adding `fadeOut()`, change the content of the `<strong>`-node, `fadeIn()` and you're basically done. What exactly is your problem? Where did you get stuck?